# Inequality of arithmetic and geometric mean

Tags: inequality

I did a proof for inequality below, anyone has a other proof?

Let $a$ and $b$ be positive real numbers, and $t$ the parameter. Prove that:

$$a+b\geq 2\sqrt{1-t^2}\sqrt{ab}+(a-b)t$$

Comment: I suppose $t \in [0,1]$?

Comment: a known proof for the generalized form uses induction

Comment: Of course!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Did you use calculus or I have a way

Comment: I didn't use calculus i used Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and trig functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f (t)=Rhs $ of inequality . So differentiating and setting it equal to $0$ gives $\frac {2t}{\sqrt {1-t^2}}=\frac {a-b}{\sqrt {ab}} $ squaring both sides and solving we have $t=\frac {a-b}{a+b} $ thus putting the value of $t $ in original equation and simplifying we get it as $a^2+b^2$ now both $a,b $ are positive so $a^2+b^2\leq (a+b)^2$. Thus its proved. $$\text {another way} $$ put $t=\sin (x) $ thus $\sqrt {1-t^2}=\cos (x) $ we can do this as for the equality to give real values t has to be in $[0,1] $ thus we have $f (x)=2\sqrt {ab}\cos (x)+(a-b)\sin (x)\leq \sqrt {(2\sqrt {ab})^2+(a-b)^2}$  which is same as $\sqrt {(a+b)^2}=(a+b) $ as both $a,b $ are positive.

Answer (score 0):

Your inequality is wrong! Try $t=2$.

For $-1\leq t\leq 1$ we need to prove that
$$(1-t)a+(1+t)b\geq2\sqrt{(1-t)(1+t)ab},$$
which is just AM-GM

Comment: I do not even need to say that $-1 \leq t \leq 1$,this is obviously,  the inequality isn't wrong, Nobody here said that t can be any real...

Comment: @Israel Meireles Chrisostomo You said that "Let a,b positive real numbers, and t the parameter.", which says that $a>0$, $b>0$ and $t$ is  a real number.  I think it would better if you'll read my proof for $-1\leq t\leq1$.